# Keycloak authentication - how to set remember_me to the api request

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-services

I have keycloak version 20 installed, and api request to authenticate with username and password via REST API. I want to add remember_me to the request body, so I can extend the users refresh token (if the user wants it). Is that possible? I don't want to extend the refresh token lifespan for all sessions.

The API call is to the URI
`/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token`

I also enabled the remember me for the realm, and it is available if I authenticate in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have keycloak version 20 installed, and api request to authenticate
> with username and password via REST API.  I want to add remember_me to the request body, so I can extend the users refresh token (if the user wants it). Is that possible?

I am afraid this is not possible with [Direct Access Grant Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/resource-owner-password-flow)

From the Keycloak documentation section about the [Remember Me](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#enabling-remember-me) functionality:

> A logged-in user closing their browser destroys their session, and
> that user must log in again. You can set Keycloak to keep the user’s
> login session open if that user clicks the Remember Me checkbox upon
> login. **This action turns the login cookie from a session-only cookie
> to a persistence cookie.**

In Keycloak this feature relies on the browser cookies to work. For example, if you login with a user in one browser and then try to access the same account in another browser you are forced to authenticate the user again. It only works in the same browser (if cookies are enabled) because it was there where the cookie was originally created. Consequently, out-of-the-box, I do not see how this would work with the Direct Access Grant flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks I have to find a workaround.

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if you find out I would also be interested in knowing about it